# Getting: error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'. after adding new modules to the project

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to run an Angular Material project, and I've done all steps in this tutorial (up until *setting up styles*) - https://medium.com/@ismapro/first-steps-with-angular-cli-and-angular-material-5a90406e9a4

In short, I ran these commands one by one:

```js
npm install @angular/cli -g
ng -v
ng new angular-material-begin --style=scss
cd angular-material-begin
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/animations
ng serve
```

Once that, I've added two Angular Material modules to my *app.module.ts* file (whole code below):

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Even though, I'm getting a whole bunch of errors, like these:
*error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.*, after adding these two modules.

Please note that I've tried to install Angular CDK, run *npm install*, and all that.

It just seems that I've caught some kind of cache with previous installations and just can't get through.

Appreciate any help or support.

**EDIT** What I'm seeing when I click on the link in those errors (each file just shows that it cannot find this @angular/core thing:
[image]

Comment: Double check your node_modules folder
Does it exists if yes check path
There must be a package.json file, and try to run only 
npm install

Comment: Thank you for  the help. But yes, node_modules folder exists in my project. Regarding path checking, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please explain?

Comment: Look inside node_modules for a directory called `@angular`. Inside that should be a directory called `core`, and inside that (among other things) should be a file called `index.d.ts`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do see that and was able to find that file, which contains a single export: export * from './public_api';

Comment: Hmmm.. looks like it is there then. Do you see this error when compiling / building, or is it only shown in the IDE?

Comment: Doesn't look like that I see it. Just a ton of Cannot find module '@angular/core'. I just updated the original post with a screenshot.

Comment: mate, I just followed the exact same steps and the app is purring like a kitten. What version of CLI are you on? I am running 6.0.8. Maybe delete your project and install it again. It seems all your typings are node_modules are having issues. This shouldn't happen out of the box.

Comment: Where is `tab-content.d.ts` stored? From looking at the path in that image it's not within the same project as `index.d.ts` or `app.module.ts`

Comment: Hmm... It's strange. I checked my CLI version via console (npm angular-cli -v), I got 5.5.1. But when I checked in my package.json (in this project), I see "@angular/cli": "~6.1.2",

Comment: Update your global CLI to 6 at least, if you do `ng -v` outside a project you should see 5.5.5.

Comment: Yeah, when I run ng -v, I get 6.1.2

Comment: okay, so you global ng cli is correct. Try creating a new project, redo your steps start at `ng new..` etc.
Before you install the angular material modules, just do a `ng serve` and see if the app runs normally. Also check you VS Code. It was all fine for me

Comment: P.S. Note that the Angular Animations package should be installed and included by default in a new app created by the CLI.

Comment: Could you try `npm ls @angular/core`? And could you post a GitHub repo or Stackblitz so that we can see what causes the issue?